# The same data in multiple data structures - the right approach

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, dictionary

I am writing simple Book management (library) application, but I am confised with right data reprezentation.

I have classes like:

```
Book (isbn, author, title, libraryIdNumber)  
BookDatabase (collection of Books)
```

In this example the main data structure inside BookDatabase is a

```
Map<Integer, Book>  booksById;
```

where key is a unique library identifier of the book (for example incremental int value), and the value is just Book instance.
It is now easy to find a book by ID, but it is hard to find all books with the same title. So I would need another data structure like

```
Map<String, List<Book>> booksByTitle;
```

where the key is title of the book, and the value is a list of all books with this title in library (for example 10 copies of "Lion King").

I know that the best way to store such data would be just database, but question is more general:
Is it ok to store the same data in many data structures inside one storage class or it is memory inefficient?  Or maybe it is better to get additional representation of the data when it is actually needed (for example by invoking Map.values() method)?
What is the best approach in such case in your opinion?

Comment: For booksByTitle you can use a [multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Comment: Yeap I read about it, but in this case question is about java collections framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok to store the same data in many data structures inside one storage class or it is memory inefficient?

Yes.  You'll just be copying the references to your Book objects, not the actual Book objects themselves -- so it is memory-efficient.

P.S. You are right that a database would be better: it makes querying very easy, for example.